# Installing patches on Magento 1.6.1.0 - ERROR with existing folders "/app/etc/"

Tags: security, patches, ce-1.6.1.0

I would like to ask you some help.. I'm working on installing the security patches on Magento 1.6.1.0
I think I'm doing correctly. I uploaded the patches for the version, on the Magento root as you can see in the SSH results >>

```
login as: ssh.mydomain.com.ar
ssh.mydomain.com.ar@ssh.user.com.ar's password:
Linux 2.6.32.23-grsec.
ssh.mydomain.com.ar@ssh:/$ cd www/mydomain.com.ar/htdocs/tiendavirtual
ssh.mydomain.com.ar@ssh:/www/mydomain.com.ar/htdocs/tiendavirtual$ ls
FileuploaderInstallationManual.docx includes
LICENSE.html index.php
LICENSE.txt index.php.sample
LICENSE_AFL.txt install-em0006.php
PATCH_SUPEE-1533.sh install.lib.php
PATCH_SUPEE-5346.sh install.php
PATCH_SUPEE-5994.sh js
RELEASE_NOTES.txt lib
app mage
applypatch.php media
core php.ini.sample
cron.php pkginfo
cron.sh robots.txt
downloader shell
errors sitemap.xml
favicon.ico skin
get.php sp-magento-patch.php
google51d0b8abd14122e0.html var
<ww/mydomain.com.ar/htdocs/tiendavirtual$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-1533.sh
PATCH_SUPEE-1533.sh: line 25: wc: command not found
PATCH_SUPEE-1533.sh: line 25: ((: > 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 0 ")
PATCH_SUPEE-1533.sh: line 32: which: command not found
PATCH_SUPEE-1533.sh: line 33: which: command not found
PATCH_SUPEE-1533.sh: line 34: which: command not found
PATCH_SUPEE-1533.sh: line 35: which: command not found
PATCH_SUPEE-1533.sh: line 36: which: command not found
PATCH_SUPEE-1533.sh: line 38: PATCH_SUPEE-1533.sh: command not found
ERROR: "/app/etc/" must exist for proper tool work.
ssh.mydomain.com.ar@ssh:/www/mydomain.com.ar/htdocs/tiendavirtual$
```

The strange thing is the "/app/etc/" folder exist.
Do you know what can I do to install them correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The actual error starts at `wc: command not found`

The patch script needs a few system commands that it cannot find. Maybe the problem is your default shell, try to run it with `bash` instead of `sh`.

If that doesn't help, install missing packages or run the script on another system